# Python extract sql itself from parameterized sql to analyse slow queries

Tags: python, regex

I'm confused to this requirement.

In mysql.slow_log table there're too many sqls which are the same actually.

```
select * from a where a>1 and b='r' and c=3;
select * from a where a>2 and b='x' and c=5;
```

I don't care about the param value but only focus the sql itself like:

```
select * from a where a>? and b='?' and c=?
```

this is my expectation and it shows that a,b and c need combine index.

I want all digit->? and quoted char->'?'. regardless all operator including = >< between ...

how can I achieve it in Python? any help is appreciated.

Comment: how would you process this `select * from a where a IN ('1', '2', '3', '4') and b='r';` ?

Comment: select * from a where a In ('?', '?', '?', '?') and b='?'
——————
select * from a where a In (?,?,?,?) and b=? is accepted too

Comment: another case `select * from a where a REGEXP '[0-9]+' or a like '%a' ;`

Comment: select * from a where a REGEXP '?' or a like '?' ;

our sql is programmatic and simple

Comment: I wrote that variations to make a hint that the solution is too broad

Comment: the potential solution should consider all possible sql operators which can be specified in where clause

Answer (score 0):

this is what I wrote myself. It works for me.

```
# to de-parameterize sql. uniform sql
# replace value with ?
def _formatSQL(sql):
    sarr = sql.split("'")
    sarr[1::2] = ['?' for x in sarr[1::2]]
    aa = "'".join(sarr)
    return re.sub(r"\b\d+\b", "?", aa)
```